# No three-component 8bits-per-channel DXGI texture format in D3D11?

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, directx-11

Currently implementing a D3D11 renderer, and the majority of my normal maps are in 3-channel RGB 8bits-per-channel format.

Looking through the [DXGI_FORMAT msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059(v=vs.85).aspx) I've noticed that there's no option for this. What's the reasoning behind this? How would I use this texture format then?

Comment: You should go through this tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut20.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hardware that support a 24bits format texture for a good decade now.

You have different options now :

- Expand to 32bits. You retain the full quality of the bitmap at the price of an extra memory cost, no extra processing need.
- Use a compressed format. This is where you should head.

GPU are not the best at reading a lot of uncompressed textures. Of course, if you are only rendering a few models, it won't matter, but if you start pushing a larger amount of data, you have to go to the compressed road.

Your compression options if you support very old hardware:

- BC1, RGB format with 4bits per pixel, worst quality, use only with giant textures when the saving overcome the quality, or better, never use it.
- BC3 with Red/Alpha swap, 4bit per pixel, just slightly better.

You should consider these instead :

- BC5 : 8bits per pixels, 2 channels, you will have to rebuild Z with `sqrt(1 - dot(n.xy,n.yx))` or an equivalent tricks.
- BC7 : 8bits per pixels, 3/4 channels, the best choice if you need to store something else with your normal, like a variance. This format is great but is also very CPU intensive to generate at his best quality.

On a side note, do not forget to generate a mip chains up to an 1x1 size, it is both for performance and visual quality. Do not apply a SRGB conversion like you should have for your albedos ( 0.5 is really 0.5) and you have options with some formats to use an SNORM type to skip the typical `2*n-1` formula but be carreful with the 0 case.